# I guess there is some mistake in the function

Tags: c

I would appreciate if anyone can help me figuring out why is this fuction (fn) does not print the int array elements?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fn (int arr[], int s);
int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {5, 2, 0, 9, 7}, s=5;
    fn (arr, s);
}

fn(int arr[], int s)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);
    {
        arr[i]++;
        printf("%d ", arr[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);` remove last `;`. Also `fn(int arr[], int s) {` --> `void fn(int arr[], int s) {`

Comment: This would be a perfect time to learn how to use a debugger, so you can figure out silly typos like this yourself.

Comment: Why do you pass the length of the array to the function and then ignore it and use a hard-coded `5` in your loop condition?

Comment: Ken, you're right. But the CodeBlocks debugger is dim, and when I click on it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Dmitri, when I initially wrote the code I put s in the for loop, but when it didn't work, I tried some changes including hard-coded 5 instead of s.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

The semicolon at the end of the expression terminates the for-loop before  even entering the body of the loop. Hence the body is seen as a stand-alone block of code by the compiler, unrelated to the for-loop.

Since the body of the loop is detached from the for-loop, variable `i` (the counter of the for-loop) is out of scope since `i` is local to the for-loop, and can only be called inside it as it was declared inside the conditional statement of the for-loop.

To fix this problem, remove the semicolon at the end of the for-loop condition.